# mysql select distinct date takes FOREVER on database w/ 374 million rows

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-optimization, bigdata

I have a MYSQL DB with table definition like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `minute_data` (
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `open` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `high` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `low` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `close` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `volume` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `adj_close` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `symbol` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`symbol`,`date`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

It stores 1 minute data points from the stock market.  The primary key is a combination of the symbol and date columns.  This way I always have only 1 data point for each symbol at any time.

I am wondering why the following query takes so long that I can't even wait for it to finish:

> select distinct date from test.minute_data where date >= "2013-01-01"
>   order by date asc limit 100;

However I can `select count(*) from minute_data;` and that finishes very quickly.

I know that it must have something to do with the fact that there are over 374 million rows of data in the table, and my desktop computer is pretty far from a super computer.

Does anyone know something I can try to speed up with query?  Do I need to abandon all hope of using a MySQL table this big??

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of your schema, but instead the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE minute_data`.

Comment: why don't u try the query on a smaller database say 10 rows and the same schema. If it works, then you'll know its the size of the database

Comment: It looks like you have a composite primary key, containing both `symbol` and `date`. If `date` is first in the key, searching and grouping it should be quick, but if it's second it will have to scan all rows.

Comment: Thank you, updated the question with table definition.  Date is second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a composite index on 2 columns, like your `(symbol, date)` primary key, searching and grouping by a prefix of they key will be fast. But searching for something that doesn't include the first column in the index requires scanning all rows or using some other index.

You can either change your primary key to `(date, symbol)` if you don't usually need to search for `symbol` without `date`. Or you can add an additional index on `date`:

```
alter table minute_data add index (date)
```

Comment: I ran a similar query selecting distinct symbols, and it works pretty quickly, so I am adding the index on date to see if it helps.

Comment: it took over 6 hours to add the index, but after that the query in my question finished instantly.